# JBoss Seam - ViewExpiredException

Tags: java, jboss, seam, web.xml

I currently have a web application which acts as a Portal. Users log onto the Portal and are shown a list of services. To view a service, an iframe is populated in the same page pointing to the URL of the service. All applications are Seam 2.1.1GA on JBoss 4.2.2GA AS.

If a user loads up Service A, interacts with it, then switches using the menu in the Portal to Service B, interacts with it, then switches back to Service A and goes to interact, they get a ViewExpiredException (it's not actually shown to the user, I've got some code to display an error message rather than redirect etc.)

I have tried using

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
```

in web.xml. This gets rid of the ViewExpiredException, but throws an error on the AS stating that a transaction is required, or it can't join an existing transaction.

The bean we use at the backend has a method annotated @Begin(join=true). I've tried removing join=true but that throws more errors.

I'm totally stumped, and have been scratching my head for ages! Any ideas?

Many thanks,

Chris

Answer (score -1):

There is some information on this on the Seam Community site, that might be of help to you: http://seamframework.org/Community/ViewExpiredExceptionIssues

Comment: This link is broken.